# 音付きで画面を録画する方法。

Tags: ios, objective-c

音つきで画面を録画する方法について検討しています。
ASScreenRecorderというライブラリを使って、音なしで画面を録画することはできました。
画面の録画と同時に、声も録音したいと思っています。

画面を録画しながら声も録音するというのは、
ゲーム実況などで重宝されると思うのですが、
これを実現するライブラリはないのでしょうか？

もしないとするならば、
画面を録画、声を録音し、後で２つをくっけて動画にするという方法でできますでしょうか？
詳しい方、ご教示ください。

Answer (score 1):

iPhoneの画面を音付きで録画したいということでよろしいでしょうか？

その場合、USBでiPhoneとMacを接続し、QuickTimePlayerを起動すれば特別なアプリケーションをインストールしなくても、iPhoneの画面と音を録画することができます。

iPhoneから鳴る音とMacに接続しているマイクの声の音を同時に録音したい場合、SoundFlowerという非公式のアプリケーションを導入して、Audio MIDI設定でinputやoutputを正しく設定する必要があります。